# update system in WPF

Tags: xml, wpf

I can create a file on the server (can be xml or asp) to do the version comparison.

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"> 
<Application> 
<Version> 1.2.3.5 </ Version> 
<ZipFile> Name_App_1.2.3.5.zip </ ZipFile> 
</ Application>
```

But how would I do so in WPF for the Load event loading the application check the version of the installed application and bottom that contained the server. 
Download version if lower, would.

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some kind of update service or version checking yourself.

You can use a third party application that will update your application automatically.  Products like Lindersoft SetupBuilder and InstallShield have these types of services implemented with them.

If you don't go that route, you need to do some sort of `HttpClient` to check the file on the server and do your comparison.  If an update is available, you need to then download the current '.exe' on the server to the local machine and run the setup '.exe' using your application, or start a service to run the install and close your application to avoid installation issues & making the need for the computer to restart.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. It may not have expressed myself correctly. 
So I need a method that loads in the application Window_Loaded pointing to the site on the server that will store the system update. 
Through an xml file as mentioned above would be checked if the system is upgraded or there is an available update to be downloaded. 
Hence this method would download and desconpactação saving the file in the installation directory. 
The detail that the computer does not need to be restarted. only the application restarts. 
If you can help me get started with this method, will be grateful

Comment: sorry, descompactação = unzip.